# This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded our test site to Civi 4.6.9 on WP 4.3.1 and all is ok.  I upgraded Civi on our live site and the upgrade was successful.  However, when I go into the Civi Menus sometimes I get "This webpage has a redirect loop   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".  On the Administer menu I always get this error.
What can I do to fix this problem?   (ps. deleting cookies, etc. didn't help)

Answer (score 4):

This issue was a WP Plugin "WordPress HTTPS" was conflicting with Civi |Administer| Resource URLs and  Force Secure URLs(SSL) checked as Yes.

We deactivated the WP Plugin and all is ok!

Comment: Thanks Gary, perhaps you could add your findings to this page in the Wiki as well? http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+plugins+incompatible+with+CiviCRM